# Find the optimal weighting distribution for a die given a set prize values

Tags: probability, optimization, constraints, utility

Say you have $B$ boxes, each of which contains a prize of value $v_b$. You have a $B$-sided die, and you win the value of box $b$ by rolling $b$. You get $R$ rolls, and so can collect multiple prizes, but you can’t win the same box more than once.

Given you know $R$, $B$, and all the box values $v_b$,how do you choose to weight your die as to optimize your expected total reward?

**My attempts so far**
I've tried two approaches. Both share the definition of expected value:

$U = \sum_b \sum_r  u_{b,r} $

Where

$u_{b,r} = v_b (1 - w_b)^{r-1}w_b$

The difference in my two (failed) methods is in the expression of the constraints. In one method, I let

$w_b = W_b/\sum_i W_i$

and find the critical points by differentiating with respect to every $W_b$ and setting to zero.

In the other method, I use Lagrange multiplier to express the constraint. But in both, I keep ending up with contradictions.

**Let's try a reduced version at the problem:** I'm even having a problem with the very simple case where R=1 and B=2 is. In this case, the expected value is

$U = v_1w_1 + v_2w_2$

and the constraint is

$w_1 + w_2 = 1$

The answer I'd expect is that $w_1=1$ if $v_1 > v_2$ and $w_1=0$ if $v_1 < v_2$
But, using the Lagrange multiplier method I get

$L = v_1w_1 + v_2w_2 - \lambda (1 - w_1 - w_2)$

and thus the useless set of constraints

$0=v_1 - \lambda$

$0=v_2 - \lambda$

$0=1 - w_1 - w_2$

It's been a very long time since I've had to think about multivariable calculus, so I suspect I'm doing something silly. Since this simplified function is just a plane, I'm not sure the differential method of finding maxima should work, even with the constraint. If I understand my problem with this simple case, maybe I can figure it out for the general problem.

**Context**
I'm working on an analogous problem in the context of developing a resource distribution program.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: thanks for the advice @saulspatz. Hope the background helps.

Comment: It certainly does.  I don't know that I can help you personally, but your post will get much more serious consideration now.  BTW, I think you have a stray = sign in the definition of $U$.

Answer (score 1):

The attempt at a solution above is flawed, due to the fact that it doesn't take into account that each box can be only earned once. This creates a natural notion of stopping time within the problem that changes it's structure completely.

Let's keep this to $B=2$ now and generalize later. The weights of the die being $p_1, p_2$, we would like to calculate the expectation value of the winnings after $R$ attempts. After $R$ attempts it is still possible that the game has not ended yet; the strings of rolls (11...1), (22...2)  satisfy the condition. These are also the only strings in the game that earn you less than $v_1+v_2$ (all the others eventually stopped before the R-th attempt yielding the full amount). The winnings EV is

$$\langle W_2\rangle=\sum_i W_i P_{i}=v_1 p(11...1)+v_2p(22...2)+(v_1+v_2)(1-p(11..1)-p(22...2))$$

or more explicitly
$\langle W\rangle=v_1(1-p_2^R)+(1-p_1^R)v_2$

We can now use Lagrange multipliers on this to yield that the values that maximize the average winnings are

$$p_1=\frac{v_1^{\frac{1}{R-1}}}{v_1^{\frac{1}{R-1}}+v_2^{\frac{1}{R-1}}}~~, ~~p_2=\frac{v_2^{\frac{1}{R-1}}}{v_1^{\frac{1}{R-1}}+v_2^{\frac{1}{R-1}}}$$

For $B=3$ we consider the same setup and find the strings that do not terminate the game after $R$ attempts. These are comprised of the strings that contain **only** one or two of the 3 potential outcomes. Counting the probability of those strings is relatively simple and the expected winnings are

$$\langle W_3 \rangle=\sum_{i=1}^3 v_ip_i^R+(v_1+v_2)(p_1+p_2)^R+(v_2+v_3)(p_2+p_3)^R+(v_3+v_1)(p_3+p_1)^R+(v_1+v_2+v_3)(1-\sum_i p_i^R-(p_1+p_2)^R-(p_2+p_3)^R-(p_3+p_1)^R)$$

This already has become too difficult to maximize analytically. This can be generalized to a die of arbitrary number of sides $B$- just consider $S=$ all the $2^B-2$ subsets of the sets $\{1,2,..., B\}$ that are not empty and not the set itself and the winnings expected are

$$\langle W_B\rangle=\sum_{s\in S}\left[\left(\sum_{i\in s} v_i\right)\left(\sum_{j\in s}p_j\right)^R\right]+\left(1-\sum_{s\in S}\left(\sum_{i\in s}p_i\right)^R\right)\sum_{j=1}^{B}v_j$$

Still, other than the obvious situation when $v_1=v_2=...v_B$ where the maximization is achieved by $p_1=p_2=...=p_B=\frac{1}{B}$ for other winnings per box, the solution is not to my knowledge available analytically, and one has to resort to computational methods.